# populate result column based on multiple rows value

Tags: sql

I need to be able to analyze multiple rows into one row in the output with a status value that summarizes the status column like this: 
I have this table

```
+------+--------------+
| EmployeeID|   Status| 
+---------------------+
| 997624    | complete|
| 997624    | complete|
| 997624    | complete|
| 556723    | complete| 
| 556723  |incomplete |
| 556723    | complete|
| 556723 | incomplete |
+------+--------------+
```

I want to be able to run query to summarize this table into the following
if the employee has all complete the result would be

```
+------+--------------+
| EmployeeID|   Status| 
+---------------------+
| 997624    | complete|
```

But if the employee has only one incomplete, his result would be incomplete

```
+------+--------------+
| EmployeeID|   Status| 
+---------------------+
| 556723 | incomplete|
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only values `complete` and `incomplete` are available in the table, this should do it:

```
select 
    employee_id, 
    max(status) status
from mytable
group by employee_id
```

This works because `'incomplete' > 'complete'`.

Otherwise, you can proceed as follows:

```
select 
    employee_id, 
    case 
        when max(case when not status = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 'complete'
        when max(case when status = 'incomplete' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then 'incomplete'
        else 'some default'
    end
from mytable
group by employee_id
```

Comment: Status can have different values other than incomplete, sometimes it has Not Yet started

Comment: @Lisa: ok, I edited my answer with a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_emp_table') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #my_emp_table
END;


CREATE TABLE #my_emp_table (EmployeeID INT NOT NULL, [STATUS] nvarchar(max) NULL);

INSERT INTO #my_emp_table([EmployeeID], [STATUS])
       VALUES  (997624,'complete')
              ,(997624,'complete')
              ,(997624,'complete')
              ,(556723,'complete') 
              ,(556723,'incomplete')
              ,(556723,'complete')
              ,(556723,'incomplete')

--select * from #my_emp_table

SELECT DISTINCT m.[EmployeeID], tbl.CNT,
  CASE WHEN CNT > 1 THEN 'incomplete' ELSE 'complete' END AS [Status]
  FROM #my_emp_table m
  JOIN (
      SELECT [EmployeeID], COUNT(distinct [status]) AS CNT FROM #my_emp_table GROUP BY [EmployeeID]
  ) tbl ON m.[EmployeeID] = tbl.[EmployeeID]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly hacky way of doing this

```
select 
employee_id, 'complete' as status
from your_table
group by employee_id
having avg(case when status='complete' then 1 else 0 end)=1
```